# Android phone file structure seems corrupted when connected via USB

Tags: file-system, file-management, system-error

so I have a Sony Xperia Play, and it's worked for awhile, but now I'm finding that sometimes when I plug it into my MacBook through USB, and try to copy files from the EasyVoiceRecorder folder onto my computer, I will get

"unknown" -39 errors
- Sometimes the file I copy is starts to copy over but then replaces itself. Example: Copying Recording 256. You see Recording 256 start to put itself on the desktop, but at the last second it becomes Recording 44 that's ACTUALLY put itself on the desktop. To fix this (SOMETIMES THIS WORKS) I put Recording 44 on the desktop and THEN copy the Recording 256, and it works.

- Other things like that.

What's happening and how can I fix it? Do I need to reinstall the app maybe?

Also, I modify/delete the audio files in EasyVoiceRecorder directly from the directory, not from the phone. Could that've messed with the structure?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this problem occur from the SD card?

Comment: Yes, this seems to be an SD card issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about doing this on a Mac, But if you have a windows PC, preferably a windows 7, try the following:-

1. Connect your phone via USB to the PC with the SD card. Turn on file sharing.
2. Go to My Computer, find your SD card "drive", right click > properties.
3. Go to Tools tab, under "Error Checking", click on "Check Now".
4. Any SD card related file system errors should get automatically fixed.